# Sql Update Loop in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I want to update my table in Posgres using c#. Here is the code:

```
        string[] new_fax = label17.Text.Split(',');
        string[] new_names = label19.Text.Split(',');
        label17.Text = new_fax[0];
        label19.Text = new_names[1]; 

        string strConnString = "Server=" + path_server + ";Port=" + path_port + ";User Id=" + path_username + ";Password=" + path_password + ";Database=****";
        try
        {
            foreach(var data in new_fax)
            {
                foreach (var name_new in new_names)
                {
                    NpgsqlConnection objConn = new NpgsqlConnection(strConnString);
                    string strSelectCmd = "update tbl_account set balance =" + label17.Text + " where account_name like '%" + label19.Text + "%'";
                    MessageBox.Show(strSelectCmd.ToString());
                    objConn.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    NpgsqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(strSelectCmd, objConn);
                    objDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                    objConn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Success");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

The problem is that its not going inside the loop where there are two values in label.text.

Can i have some Help????

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint? For the record I kind of think you want `textbox17.Text` but thats a complete guess

Comment: Step into your code und manually check your 2 arrays.

Comment: Use [Paramerized Queries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx) to avoid SQL Injection (and subtle bugs with data in general).

Comment: oh dear lord, you ask for some sql injection? maybe from label1 to label18 too?

Comment: label17 got 1050,2050 and label19 got alpha, beta

Comment: @user3200722 - What do `new_fax` and `new_names` contain at the point before you iterate with your foreach loop?

Comment: 1050,2050 and  alpha, beta

Comment: If its not getting the results you were expecting its probably because you never use `data` or `name_new`, you're just reusing the label text

Comment: what i can see is its just updaing only one part 1050 and alpha...2050 and beta are not updating

Comment: See my above comment then,I have VTC as simple typographical error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not using the apropriate values from your loops. Second: Use paramerterized queries for heavens sake. Google SQL injection please.

Your code should look like this: Do not use your textboxes but the values from your foreach loops.

```
foreach(var data in new_fax)
{
    foreach (var name_new in new_names)
    {
        NpgsqlConnection objConn = new NpgsqlConnection(strConnString);
        string strSelectCmd = "update tbl_account set balance = @data where account_name LIKE '@name_new'";
        strSelectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", data);
        strSelectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_new", "%" + name_new + "%");
        /* ....  */
    }
}
```